# Leer archivo settings desde otro proyecto c#

Tags: c#

De qué manera puedo leer el archivo `settings.settings` de un proyecto A desde un proyecto B. Intenté con `ConfigurationManager` pero solo accede a las configuraciones de aplicación, por lo que leí no era muy realizable pero que alternativas hay? La idea es simplemente leer los valores desde el proyecto B.

El proyecto A (principal) hace referencia al B pero no al revés.

saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible hacer lo que pides directamente.

La solución pasa por crear una clase pública en el proyecto B, que lea el contenido de su configuración, exponiendo estos datos a otra aplicación.

Desde la aplicación A, ahora podrás hacer referencia a la clase creada en el proyecto B y acceder a los datos que necesites.